# Como retornar solo el valor que va especificado en el filtro mongoDB con node y express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

tengo este json que contiene arrays dentro donde quiero acceder a la propiedad de specialties.name para realizar el filtro:

```
   "nameInstitution":"alemana",
   "logo":"img",
   "branchOffices":[
      {
         "name":"Dávila",
         "address":"Addres Test",
         "sector":"North",
         "specialties":[
            {
               "name":"Cardiologia adulto",
               "appointments":[
                  {
                     "hour":"20:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "hour":"10:00"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Cardiologia infantil",
               "appointments":[
                  {
                     "hour":"09:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "hour":"23:00"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Lo que deseo es retornar según el filtro. Hasta ahora intente con esto:

```
find({
      'branchOffices.specialties': {
         '$elemMatch': {
           'name': "Cardiologia adulto"
            }
         }
      });
```

Pero me devuelve el objeto entero al encontrar alguna coincidencia.

Lo que espero es que solo devuelva la coincidencia del filtro en este caso que el name sea *Cardiologia adulto* como lo siguiente:

```
       "nameInstitution":"alemana",
       "logo":"img",
       "branchOffices":[
          {
             "name":"Dávila",
             "address":"Addres Test",
             "sector":"North",
             "specialties":[
                {
                   "name":"Cardiologia adulto",
                   "appointments":[
                      {
                         "hour":"20:00"
                      },
                      {
                         "hour":"10:00"
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]

          }
       ]
    }
```

Como puedo realizar esto?

Comment: Hola. Estas usando Mongoose?  en caso de que no, puedes (o tienes licencia) implementarlo en la app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la respuesta que esperas no es muy grande, puedes filtrarlo después de la consulta.

O sino, puedes intentarlo con un `aggregate`, usando `$map`y un `$filter`:

```
db.collection("your_collection").aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "branchOffices.specialties": {
        $map: {
          input: "$branchOffices.specialties",
          as: "me",
          in: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$$me",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.name",
                  "Cardiologia adulto"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```